# ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_EXIST on Microsoft Surface Pro

Tags: boot, drivers, 17.10, surface

I am new to Ubuntu and not very familiar with it. My Problem:

I want to run Ubuntu 17.10 on my Surface Pro 2017. I have installed the [linux-surface](https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface) kernel from jakeday which works fine. The most things work out (touch, display port, ...) except the power and volume button which isn't a problem for me. The thing I cannot live with is that the battery status isn't shown. I'm not sure where the problem arises, since it already existed after the custom installation of Ubuntu.

I think this relates to a error I get while booting the system. The log files includes the following errors:

`/var/log/kern.log`

```
Mar 13 08:12:25 daniel-Surface-Pro kernel: [    6.922232] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [OR01] (0000000046bb44e5) [GenericSerialBus] (20170831/evregion-166)
Mar 13 08:12:25 daniel-Surface-Pro kernel: [    6.922235] ACPI Error: Region GenericSerialBus (ID=9) has no handler (20170831/exfldio-299)
Mar 13 08:12:25 daniel-Surface-Pro kernel: [    6.922239] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB._SAN.RQST, AE_NOT_EXIST (20170831/psparse-550)
Mar 13 08:12:25 daniel-Surface-Pro kernel: [    6.922244] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \ADP1.ACST, AE_NOT_EXIST (20170831/psparse-550)
Mar 13 08:12:25 daniel-Surface-Pro kernel: [    6.922247] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \ADP1._PSR, AE_NOT_EXIST (20170831/psparse-550)
Mar 13 08:12:25 daniel-Surface-Pro kernel: [    6.922251] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_EXIST, Error reading AC Adapter state (20170831/ac-139)
```

`/var/log/syslog`

```
Mar 13 08:41:04 daniel-Surface-Pro org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[975]: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
Mar 13 08:41:04 daniel-Surface-Pro org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[975]: This incident has been reported.
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is known, this is a reported issue in Jakedays' Github repository (see https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface/issues/195) and a "missing driver" bug at kernel.org: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198145. As I have the same problem, I'm waiting for a driver as well.

Second thing, the "not authorized"-error in your syslog is not ACPI-related but a problem of automatic brightness. See `/var/log/auth.log` for details:

```
Jun 6 08:39:11 sp pkexec[7071]: gdm: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/var/lib/gdm3] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper —set-brightness 3450]
```

This bug is "confirmed" here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1584457 and a quick solution would be

```
systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy.service
```

I hope this helps in the meantime, while waiting for ACPI drivers!